# Translate words in login module

Tags: joomla-2.5, language

I would like to know the best / easiest way to change words to another language in Joomla 2.5.

I'm using a Helix template, Shaper II Store, and most of the website is in Spanish, but some words are in English... How can I translate it? Here's an example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, fixed.
I just modified the php file of the login module.
It was wrote in this way:

```
<?php echo JText::_('  '); ?>
```

I only had to put the text that I wanted inside the parenthesis

Comment: if you do it like this, then it is best to do it with a template override. Otherwise see the suggestion for Language Override by @Jextn. You can create a language override for the language string you replaced in the php code.

Answer (score 1):

Goto backend -> Extensions -> Language Manager -> Override -> New -> See one search box is available.
Here you can give constant or value. constant means for example (com_content) and value means for example (read more) and you can translate or override the language.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to install the Spanish language pack via the Joomla admin panel.

Go to:

**Extensions** >> **Language Manager** >> **Install Language**

Then select "**Spanish**" from the list and click "**Install**"

Comment: It was already done...

Comment: Is the login module you're using a 3rd party extension?

Comment: I don't think so. I guess It's part of the template

Comment: Well if it's the default login module then the Spanish language pack you have installed should work. It's not working so it's 1 of 2 things. Either the template you're using has done a template override for the module and removed the language strings, or you're using a 3rd party extension for the login module, such as Community Builder. You need to find this information out. You should also contact the developer of your template

Comment: What about finding the language file and change the constant values?

Comment: If you're going to do that, I suggest you override the language string using Joomla's Language Manager. Do not override the actual file!

Comment: OK, fixed. I just modified the php file of the login module. It was wrote in this way: <?php echo JText::_('string'); ?>

Comment: @Antonio - Please add your fix as an answer and accept it so people know it has been solved